# Android Studio not importing AAR file correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, android-library, aar

I've created an Android library and I've exported it as an AAR file. I try importing the AAR file into another project by going to File > Project Structure > + > Import .JAR/.AAR Package > select AAR directory > Finish. Instead of importing the AAR file, I just get a directory with the AAR file inside of it like so:

[image]

I'm expecting an imported library to look like this:

[image]

From what I can tell, I exported the AAR file correctly. When I change the file type to .jar, it shows all the contents I want to import into my project. Any ideas?

Comment: Whatever you did is correct. In fact, both the screenshots look like same (one with collapse and one with expanded). I didn't get what you want.